# Why are vectors-as-arrows insufficient for defining tangent vectors on a manifold?

Tags: vectors

I am reading *Gravity* by Hartle and *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler. Both books at some point say that vectors-as-arrows are not sufficient to use for measuring curvature on a manifold. Instead we must use the directional derivative operator and an affine parameterization of the curve. MTW say that vector-as-arrow is a bilocal concept that implies two points: a tip and a tail. We need a vector concept that is defined at one point. And that's what the directional derivative operator gives us.

**My Question:**

I recognize the problem with having a bilocally defined vector. But how does the directional derivative operator solve that problem?

Comment: Well for starters it has removed the problem of two points. It gives the desired information using one point. Second, since it is an operator, it gives a deeper viewpoint by allowing it to act on another space - the space of functions. This is tied in with derivations, and ultimately with the general principle that we would like to have the sheaf of functions and maps from them kept as part of the structure (for example think about varieties and coordinate rings).